# Symfony2 multiple form themes in one twig not overriding

Tags: php, forms, symfony

If I have two forms in one twig page and want to render different form themes it does not work. Both my forms have the first theme that is rendered. For example:

in config.yml:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        register_form_theme:       'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_theme.html.twig'
        register_form_popup_theme: 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_popup_theme.html.twig'
```

In my twig I do like this:

```
<form>
     {% form_theme form register_form_theme %}

...

</form>

<form>
     {% form_theme form register_form_popup_theme %}

...
</form>
```

The problem is that both forms are rendered with the first theme... why is that? Any way to make this work?

Comment: Is this the same form rendered twice?

Comment: No they are different forms

Comment: Then how come you use the the form variable for both?

Comment: Sorry, I mean yes they are the same forms, but rendered by different controllers  :)

Comment: How do you use different controllers within the same template? :) (or are you using `render(controller(...`? I think you need to add some information of how you're actually setting up that template.

Comment: Yes I am. The form theme in the render function is overriding other theme because it is set first i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations) It looks like you've to declare your themes in `form_theme` :

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        register_form_theme: 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_theme.html.twig'       
        register_form_popup_theme: 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_popup_theme.html.twig'
    form_themes:
        - 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_theme.html.twig'
        - 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_popup_theme.html.twig'
    # ...
```

I kept you global to use it in twig. But if this doesn't work, just try to type the both strings directly in your `{% form_theme form 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_popup_theme.html.twig' %}`

Comment: And what happens if you duplicate your form in your controller : `form`, `form1` and call Each one with a different theme ?

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never, since this question is ranking pretty high in StackOverflow: in Symfony2 (and up?) you can set multiple form theme within a Twig template. Syntax is (note the `with` keyword):

```
{% form_theme form with ['MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_theme.html.twig', 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_popup_theme.html.twig'] %}
```

It was discussed on [Symfony issues](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3576), but I believe it was never correctly documented.

Regarding the original question, I believe the solution is to have 2 different form themes for 2 different form view variables (`register_form` and `register_popup_form`).

```
{% form_theme register_form 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_theme.html.twig %}
{% form_theme register_popup_form 'MpShopBundle:Form/Themes:register_popup_theme.html.twig' %}
```